# Creating an Excel file in OneDrive with an uppercase extension leaves it in an odd read-only mode

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

If I have an Excel file  where the file extension is in uppercase and I use the Graph Api to save that file in OneDrive then when I open the file through the OneDrive web UI the Excel workbook has the message 'Read Only This workbook was opened in read-only mode'.

I can then press the 'Edit Workbook' button but my Addin does not appear in the ribbon after I press this.

So, this is good:

/items/[folder ID]:/myfile.xlsx:/:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession

But this leaves the file in an odd read-only mode.

/items/[folder ID]:/myfile.XLSX:/:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession

Obviously I have solved this by converting the extension to lower-case but it took me a while to work out where my problem lay.

Comment: Strange one. Can you repro the issue consistently? Glad that you can report this issue and sharing the related info. Have you file a bug for document with Microsoft? so they can consider updating it, which is useful for all.

Comment: Yes, I can repro it consistently.  I am not sure how to lodge an issue, I had understood that StackOverflow was the best way to get in touch with the OneDrive team.